# twitter bootstrap .hidden-lg less not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <script src="./assets/js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header-container">
            <header class="wrapper clearfix">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">nav ul li a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">nav ul li a</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">nav ul li a</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="promo-pod">
                <p>Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod</p>
                <p>Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod</p>
                <p>Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod</p>
                <p>Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod</p>
                <p>Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod Promo pod</p>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- #main-container -->

        <div class="footer-container">
            <footer class="wrapper">
                <h3>Footer</h3>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- Le javascript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>-->
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My less for hiding the promo-pod:

```
.main-container {

    .container();
    .make-row();

    .main.wrapper {
        .make-column(12);
    }

    .promo-pod {
        border:1px solid red;
        .hidden-lg;
        .make-column(3);
    }
}
```

I decided to change div class="promo-pod" to div class="span4 hidden-lg" and it hid the div, but when it is just div class="promo-pod", all the rules apply except the .hidden-lg;

The less file compiles correctly each time I save the file, any help is appreciated.

Changed the name to promo, as in , very long, so search for promo in this gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6174366

Comment: Can you post the .promo-pod styles from the compiled bootstrap.css file? That might help us debug the issue.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem instead of posting the whole HTML document, if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE: as of August 2013, this has been fixed in Bootstrap, so the workarounds below are no longer necessary. (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/9211)**

Bootstrap's responsive mixins aren't built to handle what you're trying to accomplish.

Poke around in [responsive-utilities.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/08cd3072fc48d8b4ad7e9062cd5e9bbea1cc19da/less/responsive-utilities.less) and [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/08cd3072fc48d8b4ad7e9062cd5e9bbea1cc19da/less/mixins.less) and you'll see that the responsive utility classes (`.hidden-lg`,`.visible-lg`, etc.) don't actually contain any @media queries, so embedding them in your CSS won't make them respond to screen size changes. For these classes to work properly, they need to be added directly into your HTML.

But as a workaround, you can copy Bootstrap's @media queries from `responsive-utilities.less` and directly apply the visibility  mixins to your styles:

```
.promo-pod {

    /* Turn element off for all screens */
    .responsive-invisibility();

    /* Turn element back on for large screens */
    @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) {
        .responsive-visibility();
    }

}
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it's the best you can do unless Bootstrap rearchitects their visible/hidden styles.

**Edit (alternative solution)**:

If you'd like to use `.visible-sm`, `.visible-lg`, etc. directly in your CSS as you first asked, then add this snippet to your LESS file:

```
.visible-sm {
  .responsive-visibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
}
.visible-md {
  .responsive-invisibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-visibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
}
.visible-lg {
  .responsive-invisibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-visibility(); }
}

.hidden-sm {
  .responsive-invisibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-visibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-visibility(); }
}
.hidden-md {
  .responsive-visibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-visibility(); }
}
.hidden-lg {
  .responsive-visibility();
  @media (min-width: @screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-tablet-max) { .responsive-visibility(); }
  @media (min-width: @screen-desktop) { .responsive-invisibility(); }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
.promo-pod {
  .visible-lg;
}
```

It's simply a reorganization of Bootstrap's responsive utilities from `responsive-utilities.less`. (I may add a pull request to Bootstrap to see if something like this can get pulled into the master branch.)